# MSSQL добавить псевдостолбец в SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица с полями |A|B|C|, мне нужно сделать запрос, где будут выводиться эти поля + дополнительное псевдополе |D|, которое постоянно равно одному значению.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT [A],[B],[C],0 as [D] FROM MyTable
```

вместо 0 - возможно указать любое значение, так же ключевое слово `AS` можно опустить.